# Wierd admin_path behaviour, does it should be like this?

Tags: hooks

I have even two questions - both are connected to hook_admin_path().

1. Does menu path `'user/*/edit'` and `'user/*/account/edit'` are the same, from admin_path perspective and was D7 designed with such functionality? I want menu item `'user/*/account/edit'` to be shown on default theme.

When I try to show a menu item with path:

```
'user/*/account/edit'  - showed on admin theme
'user/*/account/edit1' - showed on default theme

result of path_get_admin_paths():
Array ([admin] => 
admin
admin/*
user/*/cancel
user/*/edit
user/*/edit/*
...
)
```

checked with:

```
path_is_admin('user/%user/account/edit'); // TRUE
drupal_match_path('user/%user/account/edit', 'user/*/edit'); // TRUE
```

2 . I tryed to change it with

```
function MY_MODULE_admin_paths_alter() {
  $paths = array(
    'user/*/edit' => FALSE,
    'user/*/edit/*' => FALSE,
  );
}
```

But result of path_get_admin_paths() is the same? No other functions call hook_admin_paths_alter(). As I understand, this function shall be the last and should change admin_path.

Any ideas about that?

Comment: Look at the documentation again - what's the glaring difference between your function declaration and the example in the docs?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Clive,
I mistakenly used pattern from hook_admin_paths() and not hook_admin_paths_alter() function.

The correct way was:

```
function MY_MODULE_admin_paths_alter(&$paths) {
  $paths['user/*/edit'] = FALSE;
  $paths['user/*/edit/*'] = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You should select this as the correct answer.